# C#: I cant access my struct members

Tags: c#, struct

I'm trying this simple code below but surprisingly the compiler says

> "the name pq does not exist in current context"

However as you see it´s inside the desired scope. Even with adding getters and setters I can´t do that.

```
namespace AskYourQuestion
{
    public struct QuestionNum
    {
        public string Q1;
    }

    class Questions
    {

        QuestionNum pq = new QuestionNum();
        pq.Q1 = "hi";

    }
}
```

I want to make a `struct` with some strings and create some `classes` that initialize the strings in specific languages and in main program depends on the user language, the strings appear for him.

Comment: Put your statement inside a method

Comment: You can't put the line `pq.Q1 = "hi";` just like that in the class scope. It needs to be in a method scope

Comment: You should also learn why [mutable structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Comment: Just some tips. Structs should be avoided unless there is a good reason for them, and normally they would only be used when the struct has a fixed memory footprint. A string field, which can be variable length, instantly makes that suspicious. Also, fields, should be private, but in C# you can just replace that semicolon with `{ get; set; }` to convert it to a property and solve that problem

Comment: `QuestionNum pq = new QuestionNum() { Q1 = "hi" };` is an alternative

Comment: @LJ thanks. and can I access it from another class?

Comment: It would really help if you explained what you hope to accomplish, not just what you are doing.

Comment: @msd , yes if you set the right [Access Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers)
For example, `internal QuestionNum pq = new QuestionNum() { Q1 = "hi" };`

Comment: @DourHighArch , I wanna make a struct with some strings and create some classes that initialize the strings in specific languages and in main program depends on the user language, the strings appear for him.

Comment: “I wanna make a struct” is what you are doing, not a destination. *Why* do you “wanna” do that? What do you hope to achieve? A localizable UI? What kind of UI? ASP.NET? WinForms? Both APIs have localization built-in; you are probably on the wrong track completely.

Comment: @DourHighArch , Im building a telegram bot using its own api. actually user selects his/her language and questions appear for him/her. there's no need for user input at all. am I in the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few inputs to help you further dissect the problem.

Current:

```
namespace AskYourQuestion
{
    public struct QuestionNum
    {
        public string Q1;
    }

    class Questions
    {
        QuestionNum pq = new QuestionNum();
        // pq.Q1 = "hi"; --> This will not work
        // Why? See below        
    }
}
```

Class is a specification where we encapsulate the members it should hold.

Here the `Questions` class encapsulate a member `pq` of type `QuestionNum` and we should specify on how the `Questions` class and it's encapsulating members would be constructed.

Different ways to do this:

- Default it: `QuestionNum pq = new QuestionNum() { Q1 = "Hi" };`
- Construct it: `public Questions(string defaultValue) { this.pq.Q1 =
  defaultValue; }`
- Methods / setters

Examples for each:

---

Default it:

```
namespace AskYourQuestion
{
    public struct QuestionNum
    {
        public string Q1;
    }

    class Questions
    {
        internal QuestionNum pq = new QuestionNum() { Q1 = "Hi" };
    }
}
```

---

Construct it:

```
namespace AskYourQuestion
{
    public struct QuestionNum
    {
        public string Q1;
    }

    class Questions
    {
        internal QuestionNum pq = new QuestionNum() { Q1 = "Hi" };

        public Questions()
        {
        }

        public Questions(string defaultValue)
        {
            this.pq.Q1 = defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
Questions quest = new Questions("World");
Console.WriteLine(quest.pq.Q1);
```

---

There are many other ways, but you need to choose the best case based on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should put that line in a method or constructor...

```
 public class Questions
{

    QuestionNum pq = new QuestionNum();

    Questions()
    {
        pq.Q1 = "hi";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also

```
public struct QuestionNum
{
    public string Q1;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    QuestionNum pq = new QuestionNum()
    {
        Q1 = "something"
    };
}
```